# jQuery selector not excluding :not

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the jquery selector

```
"body *:not(.class)"
```

to bind events to everything on the page except a given class (see http://jsfiddle.net/MMrRb/)

When I do it, the :not clause is being ignored. Does anyone know why this is? My only way to hack around it is a separate jquery clause to reverse out what's being applied by "*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the style is applied to the `ul` element also, and the `two` is a child of the `ul` so the css rule is inherited by the element

My solution will is to apply the rule to only the leaf nodes, try the below solution

```
$(function() {
    $("body :not(.two):not(:has(*))").css("color", "red");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QVW7u/)

*Note: It is going to be incredibly costly... so if you get any other solution opt for it after a cost analysis*

Comment: As a general solution, the only issue I see with this is with elements which contain text nodes as well as other elements.  The text nodes will not be affected.  http://jsfiddle.net/QVW7u/2/

Comment: @JamesMontagne missed that... :)

Answer (score 5):

It is working just fine.  If you inspect the DOM in your fiddle, you will see that your `.two` element does not have a style of `color: red`.  However, your `ul` does.  Since your `.two` is in your `ul` it inherits the color.

That being said, the `*` in your selector is unneeded.  You can remove it and it will still select the same elements.